# I created a Dataset<Row> from a csv file, and then a Dataset<JeuDeDonnees> from it. How may I read JeuDeDonnees objects, one by one, like in a stream?

Tags: java, apache-spark, stream, java-stream

I have created a:

```java
// 'datasets' is the name the provider gave for that source
Dataset<Row> datasets = session.read().schema(schema).format("csv").load("datasets.csv");
```

Then a:

```
Dataset<JeuDeDonnees> jeuxDeDonnees = datasets.map((MapFunction<Row, JeuDeDonnees>)row -> 
   { /* [...mappings...] */ return new JeuDeDonnees(...); }, Encoders.bean(JeuDeDonnees.class));
}
```

That is for the data management part of my application.

I am willing to offer an access to this whole data to my services (for the end user).
I can't return to the full `List<JeuDeDonnees>` *Spark* extracted, of course: it would overflow everything.

I would like:

1. either returning `JeuDeDonnees` objects one by one, with a `Stream`

   `Stream<JeuDeDonnees> getNext()`, if possible ?
   But then, how may I link it to its underlying `jeuxDeDonnees` *Spark* dataset, a way that *Spark* stays rather smooth when returning data?
2. either returning `List<JeuDeDonnees> getNext(50)`
   but then, the mechanism would be more complicated to put in place, I think. As I should avoid something telling *Spark* "*start at offset x this time*" (for 50 `jeuxDeDonnees`), because doing so would cost a lot, for each offset move, (if it would even be possible, what I am unsure).
   ....another way to ask this question is: a `Dataset::take(int n)` method exists that returns the *n* first objects of a `Dataset`. Does another method exist that return the *n* next objects coming after?

What the proper way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

As a start of a solution, I've wrote this method that splits a `Dataset<Row>` to a `List<Dataset<Row>>` given a number of records per page wished.

```java
/**
 * Paginer un dataset en renvoyant plusieurs datasets d'un nombre maximal d'enregistrements.
 * @param session Session Spark.
 * @param dataset Dataset à diviser.
 * @param nombreObjetsParPage Nombre d'objets maximal par dataset créé.
 * @return Liste des datasets créés.
 */
public static List<Dataset<Row>> paginer(SparkSession session, Dataset<Row> dataset, int nombreObjetsParPage) {
   Objects.requireNonNull(session, "La session spark pour diviser un dataset pour sa pagination ne peut pas valoir null.");
   Objects.requireNonNull(dataset, "Le dataset à diviser pour sa pagination ne peut pas valoir null.");

   List<Dataset<Row>> sousDatasets = new ArrayList<>();

   // Si le nombre d'enregistrements demandés par page est supérieur ou égal au nombre qu'en a le dataset reçu en paramètre,
   // le renvoyer comme unique élément de la liste.
   long count = dataset.count();

   if (nombreObjetsParPage >= count) {
      sousDatasets.add(dataset);
      return sousDatasets;
   }

   // Attribuer un numéro d'index, allant de zéro à (count - 1), en regard du dataset.
   JavaPairRDD<Row, Long> rdd = dataset.toJavaRDD().zipWithIndex();

   long start = 0;
   long end = nombreObjetsParPage;

   // Alimenter une liste de datasets, chacun prenant à son tour les indexs dans [start, end[
   do {
      final long a = start;
      final long b = end;

      JavaPairRDD<Row, Long> rddSousEnsemble = rdd.filter(f -> f._2() >= a && f._2() < b);
      sousDatasets.add(session.createDataFrame(rddSousEnsemble.keys(), dataset.schema()));

      start += nombreObjetsParPage;
      end += nombreObjetsParPage;
   }
   while(start < count);

   return sousDatasets;
}
```

That complies to this test (provided you change the `Dataset<Row> catalogue` to one you have):

```java
/**
 * Obtention des Dataset de row, paginés.
 */
@Test
@DisplayName("Dataset catalogue (row, paginés) : jeux de données.")
void rowCatalogueDatasetsPagines() {
   LOGGER.info("Lecture du catalogue datagouv en Row, paginés...");
   Dataset<Row> catalogue = this.catalogueDataset.rowCatalogueDataset(this.session).limit(70);

   List<Dataset<Row>> pagines = AbstractSparkDataset.paginer(this.session, catalogue, 20);
   assertEquals(4, pagines.size(), "Le nombre de sous-datasets n'est pas celui attendu");

   for(int i=0; i < 3; i ++) {
      pagines.get(i).show(1000, false);
      assertEquals(20, pagines.get(i).count(), MessageFormat.format("Le nombre d''enregistrements du sous-datasets d''index {0}, {1}, n''est pas celui attendu", i, pagines.get(i).count()));
   }

   pagines.get(3).show(1000, false);
   assertEquals(10, pagines.get(3).count(), MessageFormat.format("Le dernier sous-dataset n''a pas le bon nombre d''enregitrements, mais {0}", pagines.get(3).count()));
}
```

To be more complete, this next method will return the sub datasets as `List<Dataset<JeuDeDonnees>>` or the object you're willing to have, given the mapper from a `Datatset<Row>` to a `Dataset<target object>` you can provide:

```java
/**
  * Paginer un dataset en renvoyant plusieurs datasets d'un nombre maximal d'objets métiers.
  * @param session Session Spark.
  * @param dataset Dataset d'enregistrements à diviser.
  * @param encoder Fonction d'encodage en dataset d'objets métiers d'un Dataset<Row>.
  * @param nombreObjetsParPage Nombre d'objets maximal par dataset créé.
  * @param <T> Type de l'objet métier cible que l'on veut obtenir.
  * @return Liste des datasets d'objet métier créés.
  */
public static <T> List<Dataset<T>> paginer(SparkSession session, Dataset<?> dataset, Function<Dataset<Row>, Dataset<T>> encoder, int nombreObjetsParPage) {
   Objects.requireNonNull(session, "La session spark pour diviser un dataset pour sa pagination en objets ne peut pas valoir null.");
   Objects.requireNonNull(dataset, "Le dataset à diviser pour sa pagination en objets ne peut pas valoir null.");
   Objects.requireNonNull(encoder, "La fonction d'encodage, du type Dataset<Row> vers le type d'objet métier désiré pour la pagination en objets d'un dataset, ne peut pas valoir null.");

   List<Dataset<Row>> blocsEnregistrements = paginer(session, dataset.toDF(), nombreObjetsParPage);
   return blocsEnregistrements.stream().map(encoder).toList();
}
```

Eventually, to get all of this, smoothly, as a `Stream<JeuDeDonnees>`, I had to create a dedicated iterator:

```java
/**
 * Un iterateur sur les datasets qui n'extrait leur contenu que si c'est nécessaire.
 * @param <T> Les éléments enfants transportés par les Dataset itérés (Dataset<T>).
 */
public class DatasetsItemIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
   /** Logger. */
   private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatasetsItemIterator.class);

   /** Itérateur sur les datasets. */
   private final Iterator<Dataset<T>> datasetIterator;

   /** Dataset actuellement parcouru. */
   private Dataset<T> currentDataset;

   /** Flux sur les objets métiers du dataset */
   private Iterator<T> elementsIterator = null;

   /** Page actuelle */
   private long currentPage = 0;

   /** Page maximale */
   private final long maxPage;

   /**
    * Construire un itérateur sur un ou plusieurs datasets.
    * @param datasets Datasets.
    */
   @SafeVarargs
   public DatasetsItemIterator(Dataset<T>... datasets) {
      this(Arrays.asList(datasets));
   }

   /**
    * Construire un itérateur sur une liste de datasets.
    * @param datasets Datasets.
    */
   public DatasetsItemIterator(List<Dataset<T>> datasets) {
      this.datasetIterator = datasets.iterator();
      this.maxPage = datasets.size();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean hasNext() {
      // Si aucun dataset n'a été encore observé, prendre le premier, s'il y en a un.
      if (this.currentDataset == null && nextDataset() == false) {
         return false;
      }

      // Si un itérateur existe sur des éléments et qu'il en a encore à donner, répondre Oui.
      if (this.elementsIterator.hasNext()) {
         return true;
      }

      // Sinon, tenter de parcourir un nouveau dataset.
      return nextDataset();
   }

   @Override
   public T next() {
      if (hasNext()) {
         return this.elementsIterator.next();
      }

      throw new NoSuchElementException("La famille de datasets n'a plus d'éléments à fournir.");
   }

   /**
    * Préparer l'itération du dataset suivant.
    * @return true s'il en existe un, et qu'il a des éléments disponibles.
    */
   private boolean nextDataset() {
      if (this.datasetIterator.hasNext() == false) {
         return false;
      }

      this.currentPage ++;
      LOGGER.info("Chargement de la page {}/{} du dataset paginé.", this.currentPage, this.maxPage);

      this.currentDataset = this.datasetIterator.next();
      this.elementsIterator = this.currentDataset.collectAsList().iterator();

      return this.elementsIterator.hasNext();
   }
}
```

And create this method:

```java
/**
 * Paginer en stream.
 * @param session Session Spark.
 * @param dataset Dataset à diviser.
 * @param encoder Fonction d'encodage.
 * @param nombreObjetsParPage Nombre d'objets par page.
 * @return Flux d'objets métiers.
 * @param <T> Classe des objets métiers renvoyés par le stream.
 */
public static <T> Stream<T> paginerEnStream(SparkSession session, Dataset<?> dataset, Function<Dataset<Row>, Dataset<T>> encoder, int nombreObjetsParPage) {
   Objects.requireNonNull(session, "La session spark pour diviser un dataset pour sa pagination en stream d'objets ne peut pas valoir null.");
   Objects.requireNonNull(dataset, "Le dataset à diviser pour sa pagination en stream d'objets ne peut pas valoir null.");
   Objects.requireNonNull(encoder, "La fonction d'encodage, du type Dataset<Row> vers le type d'objet métier désiré pour la pagination en stream d'objets d'un dataset, ne peut pas valoir null.");

   DatasetsItemIterator<T> objetsMetiersIterator = new DatasetsItemIterator<>(paginer(session, dataset, encoder, nombreObjetsParPage));
   return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(objetsMetiersIterator, Spliterator.ORDERED), false);
}
```

My solution works:

```java
/**
 * Obtention des Dataset d'objets métiers paginés, sous forme de stream.
 */
@Test
@DisplayName("Dataset catalogue (objets métiers, paginés et streamés) : jeux de données.")
void catalogueDatasetsObjetsMetiersPaginesStreames() {
   LOGGER.info("Lecture du catalogue datagouv en objets métiers, paginés et streamés...");
   Dataset<Row> catalogue = this.catalogueDataset.rowCatalogueDataset(this.session,(AbstractSparkDataset.Verification[]) null).limit(70);

   assertDoesNotThrow(() -> {
      Stream<JeuDeDonnees> jeuxDeDonnees = AbstractSparkDataset.paginerEnStream(this.session, catalogue, p -> this.catalogueDataset.catalogueDataset(p), 20);

      List<JeuDeDonnees> extrait = jeuxDeDonnees.limit(22).collect(Collectors.toList());
      assertEquals(22, extrait.size(), "Le flux n'a pas apporté le nombre de jeux de données attendu");
      LOGGER.info(ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(extrait));
   });
}
```

And I'm happy to see in my logs that only the page 1 and 2 are consumed in my test.

```
2023-04-29 08:10:08.375  INFO 101742 --- [           main] fr.ecoemploi.spark.DatasetsItemIterator  : Chargement de la page 1/4 du dataset paginé.
2023-04-29 08:10:09.677  INFO 101742 --- [           main] fr.ecoemploi.spark.DatasetsItemIterator  : Chargement de la page 2/4 du dataset paginé.
```

But it's drawback is: being slow. Because it does plenty of `filter`.

And I haven't checked (yet) deeply if my list of methods are tuned enough to ensure that when the page 2 is being served for object streaming, the page 1 can be garbage collected (if Java feels that need).

Because, if it's for that, at the end, the full whole Dataset (that was splitted in pages at the beginning) is just here in memory with its millions of objects, it wouldn't be perfect.